# Extension of a Fourier series $f(x) = \sum_n \hat f(n)e^{2\pi i k x}$ to a strip $\{ \mathrm{Im}(z) < a \} \subset \mathbb C$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be a $1$-periodic map with exponential decaying Fourier coefficients: $\hat f (n) \leq ce^{-dn}$ for some $c,d>0$. It follows that $f$ is a real-analytic function, $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$. Under which assumptions on $f$ (resp. its Fourier coefficients) can I extend $f$ to an anlytic function on a strip in the complex plane, i.e.
$$
\{ \mathrm{Im}(z) < a \} \ni z \mapsto \sum_n \hat f(n)e^{2\pi i k z}
$$
is analytic (and obviously agrees with $f$ on $\mathbb R$).

Comment: always by periodicity; show that starting from a closed interval larger than the period length - eg you can take length $2$ for the interval here - you can extend on a rectangle by compacity as you can extend on a small disc at each point, get finite cover, show the union of those contains a rectangle etc, and then translate and glue the rectangles using periodicity to get a strip